# How to save speck-mode dictionary with file?

Tags: file-local-variables, ispell, spell-checking, hunspell

What I tried, putting at the end of a file:

- `Local IspellDict: de`
- As local variable: `speck-dictionary: de`

However, neither is interpreted. When I open the file in question, `speck-mode`
always uses `en` as dictionary. The spell checker used is `hunspell`.

*What should I add to a file to change the dictionary of `speck-mode`?*

By the way, I use `speck-mode` because `flyspell-mode` is very slow on my
system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bug in Speck version 2014.08.30: The function `speck-restore-options` was
missing support for Hunspell. I added a bug fix to [speck.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/speck.el) on EmacsWiki. The new version is 2016.07.17.

For testing I assigned to `speck-hunspell-dictionary-alist`:

```
(("en" . "en_US") ("de" . "de_DE") ("es" . "es_ES"))
```

Now the German dictionary can be set at the end of the file with one of:

- `Local Dictionary: de`
- `Local Dictionary: de_DE`
- `Local IspellDict: de`
- `Local IspellDict: de_DE`

The key on the left side in the above examples can be changed by customizing
`speck-save-dictionary-regexp`.