# How to speed up flyspell-mode?

Tags: flyspell, spell-checking, hunspell

When `flyspell-mode` is active, typing is somewhat – although barely noticeable
– more sluggish than without, also marking of words.

Is it possible to somehow speed up `flyspell-mode`, maybe make it not check as
frequently?

I’m running `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570` on an
Intel Core i3 powered laptop with 8 GiB of RAM. As spell checker, I configured
`hunspell` installed from [ezwinports](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/).

Spell checking with `speck-mode` does not slow down typing, but here I ran into
[another issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24581/how-to-save-speck-mode-dictionary-with-file) (now fixed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/rolandwalker/flyspell-lazy

Besides, you can turn off flyspell-mode completely and use `M-x flyspell-buffer` instead.

You can also use my package https://github.com/redguardtoo/wucuo

It has two modes (see `wucuo-flyspell-start-mode`),

- In "normal" mode, it calls `flyspell-buffer` to check current buffer when saving file.
- In "fast" mode, it calls `flyspell-region` to check the visible region when saving file.

Comment: I assigned `flyspell-lazy-check-pending` to `M-q`, in addition to `fill-paragraph` of course. That way, if I fill a paragraph, spelling is triggered instantaneously, i.e. I don’t have to wait for flyspell-lazy. Also, I let `flyspell-buffer` run when a text file is loaded.

Comment: How did you let `flyspell-buffer` run when a text file is loaded? @feklee

Answer (score 2):

Flyspell is unfortunately slow and that is just life when using Emacs.  The minor-mode does, however, have a few built-in optimizations that are customizable.

The variables `flyspell-default-deplacement-commands` and `flyspell-deplacement-commands` are used to prevent flyspell from checking a word.  Essentially, if `this-command` (the current command) is the same as the previous command (`flyspell-previous-command`), and this command is a member of the list of deplacement commands, then do *not* check the word.  [The commands in the lists are associated with the *symbol* `flyspell-deplacement` and used internally when flyspell decides whether to check a word.]

The variables `flyspell-default-delayed-commands` and `flyspell-delayed-commands` are used to delay checking the word for `flyspell-delay` seconds.  [The commands in the lists are associated with the *symbol* `flyspell-delayed` and used internally when flyspell decides whether to delay checking a word.]

[When referring to the *symbols* `flyspell-deplacement` and `flyspell-delayed`, they are for internal usage and not meant to be customized by the user.]

Comment: I deleted my previous comments because my subsequent testing revealed that flyspell actually handles `self-insert-command` as well as can be expected with the default value of `flyspell-delay` being 3 seconds.  Try to pinpoint which commands you are executing where the delay is noticeable, and add those functions to one of the lists mentioned in the answer above.  The time consuming function is `flyspell-word`, just in case you wish to add a message for purposes of seeing when it fires while doing your testing -- once your testing is done, you can remove the message.

Comment: I now checked in `emacs -Q`: `flyspell-word` runs three times when I hit space. This is too often when I’m typing fast! Why `flyspell-word` runs three time I haven’t yet investigated, but the function is recursive, and so that may be OK. Every time I mark a word using `<C-S-right>`, then `flyspell-word` runs once, which is also way too often, slowing me down. Any suggestion?

Comment: You may wish to consider temporarily adding the following to `flyspell-word` to make testing a little easier:  `(message "flyspell-previous-command: %s | this-command: %s" flyspell-previous-command this-command)`.  That will help you identify the commands being called interactively, instead of using `C-h v last-command` or hitting `C-h k C-S-right`.  If you want to delay checking the word, then add the interactive function to the list of delayed-commands.  If you want to check just the first time, but not successive calls, then add the interactive function to the list of deplacement-commands.