# How to improve flyspell performance loading files?

Tags: flyspell

On loading large files ([~2000+ lines for example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/aedb49cbc9977fee56bb51a20980b380aca53659/src/libcollections/vec.rs)), flyspell takes a few seconds to Run.

Is there a way to have flyspell delay applying to the entire buffer on load?

Only run on visible text for instance? Or run multiple processes to get the job done faster?

---

Edit: this was caused by:

```
(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook 'flyspell-buffer)
```

Think this question should be closed.

Comment: I do not believe that flyspell checks the entire buffer by default when the minor-mode is initialized.  Instead, the default behavior is to check only the surrounding text as you type or move the cursor.  You may wish to find out where you changed the default behavior and reverse it -- e.g., comment it out in your user-configuration.  Try with `emacs -q` -- `(require 'flyspell)` and set just the `ispell-program-name` and then type `M-x flyspell-mode` on a large buffer.

Comment: I just tried with `emacs -q` using the above-mentioned settings and I was able to immediately initialize `flyspell-mode` on a buffer containing **114,437** lines of code -- no delay or wait whatsoever using Emacs 25.1.  As stated above, the default behavior is to only check words surrounding point -- not the entire buffer.

Comment: @lawlist, the file had many comments, linked in question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up flyspell-mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/how-to-speed-up-flyspell-mode)

Comment: @ideasman42: if you think your question is a duplicate, feel free to close it.  As describe your problem is different (it's not that editing is sluggish, but that opening the file takes a lot of time).  But flyspell already "only run[s] on visible text", so your description of the problem doesn't match our understanding of flyspell.  I suggest you file a bug report or investigate on your side what's *really* going on and then fix your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not delaying flyspell, this suggestion is offered by the [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlySpell) for flyspell performance in general:

> I highly suggest setting ‘flyspell-issue-message-flag’ to nil, as
>   printing messages for every word (when checking the entire buffer)
>   causes an enormous slowdown. – nschum